# Get entries in fixed order with Stash/Playa

Tags: playa, stash

So I have the following snippets of code which contain a matrix field `{people}` with a nested playa field `{section_people}`

```
{!-- Get people sections --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="people_sections" parse_tags="yes"}
    {people}
        {stash:section_people}{section_people:child_ids}{/stash:section_people}
    {/people}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- Get related people: --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="people_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="3" trim="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="people" dynamic="no" entry_id="{exp:playa:child_ids field='people'}" parse="inward" disable="{global:param_disable_default}"}
        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id} 
        [other fields]
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- Display: --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="people_sections"}
<section class="team">
    <h2>{section_title}</h2>
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="people_list" match="#{section_people}#" against="entry_id"}
        <article>{entry_id}</article>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
</section>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

What I'd like to accomplish is: keeping the playa entries in a fixed order: `640|643|639`

However, when I get the entries using the stash get_list they are returned by entry date: `643|640|639`

I see in the stash docs where I can sort by column, but is there a way to used a "fixed" sort order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your channel entries tag, use the `fixed_order` parameter instead of `entry_id`.